# multiple prints/echo through ajax (print slider)

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax, json

i want to print slider through ajax that requires printing of sliders different portions(slider div, ul, li) at different positions and json_encode() doesn't seems to help here

**CODE ajax page**

```
<?php
    $c=mysql_connect("localhost","abc","xyz");
           mysql_select_db("root"); 
        $sql = "select * from image2";
        $qc=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());       
        print  ' <div id="slider" style="display:block;position:relative;margin:15px auto 30px;">
                     <ul class="slides" style="display:none;">';

                    while($ans=mysql_fetch_array($qc))
                    {
                            $title=ucwords($ans['EVENT']." ".$ans['YEAR']);
                            print  "<li><img src='slider_images/$ans[img]' alt='$title' /></li>";
                    }
                    print '</ul></div>';
?>
```

**receiving end**

```
document.getElementById("slide").innerHTML=hey.responseText
```

Comment: please help guys its very urgent and very very important

Comment: i'm not receiving slider on receiving page... @u_mulder

Comment: Here's a big help for you: mysql_ is deprecated, start using mysqli_